# gmapsdistance for each row in dataframe

Tags: r

I tried to get the driving time and distance for two set of locations, both represented with longitudes and latitudes.
I used gmapsdistance before which will return a distance matrix for each point in two vectors. But here I only want to compute the distance for each row. So I consider to use apply function for each row.

Data seems like this

```
 unique_pair <- structure(list(latitude = c(42.018435, 42.018435, 42.120501), longitude = c(-70.846707, -70.846707, -71.233164),x.x.locationlatitude = c(42.23656924, 42.361856, 41.901186), x.x.locationlongitude = c(-70.9865341, -71.065615, -71.093756), n = c(80L, 2L, 65L)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df","tbl", "data.frame"))


abk<-apply(unique_pair,1,function(x) { gmapsdistance(
    origin =x[1]+x[2],  # start point of journey
    destination = x[3]+x[4],  # end point of journey
    mode = "driving",  # driving time
    shape = "long"  # format of output data 
    )})
```

The [1,2] [3,4] are lon and lat for two locations. But there is always error such that

If I didn't use +, they used each lon and lat separately as locations and reported result useless.

If I used + to include lat and lon as a point for location, it shows **non-numeric argument to binary operator**

I also consider to quote them but that doesn't work either.

Can any one help and provide some recommendations? Many thanks

Comment: Hi Hui, can you make this a minimum reproducible example? It is much easier to solve the problem if we can cut and paste your data and code, reproduce the same error you are getting, and then be able to develop solution to post for you. Thanks :)

Comment: It looks like the function is looking for a string, so try using: `paste0(x[42], "+", x[43])`

Comment: I just added the mini dataset, hope it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Dave2e Hi it works! Thanks